# Bash: using SED command to replace the value of a variable (the variable contains a path)

Tags: bash, shell, sed

I have 4 scripts (3 in bash and 1 py) that contains the variable path=/some/path

I would need to replace that path, with some other path, but i can't find a way how to do it. This is the code i have right now:

```
#!/bin/bash

path=${PWD}

#Replace path in scripts
sed -i -e "s|path=.*|path=${path}|g" "${path}/scripts/test.sh"
```

But this code doesn't replace only the content of my var. It replaces all the occurrences of "path" inside the test.sh. It also replace this

```
"${f##*/}"
```

with the output of ${PWD} (and for this one, i really don't understand why).

EDIT: part of code from test.sh

```
#!/bin/bash

path=${HOME}/project
pic_path=${path}/test_plan/tests/*
log_name=results_$(date +'%d-%m-%y-%T').log
log_path=${path}/test_plan/logs/${log_name}
csv_name=results_$(date +'%d-%m-%y-%T').csv
csv_path=${path}/test_plan/test_results/${csv_name}
filename_no_path="${f##*/}"
```

After running the above script, everything changes to:

```
path=/home/name/project
pic_path=/home/name/project
log_name=results_$(date +'%d-%m-%y-%T').log
log_path=/home/name/project
csv_name=results_$(date +'%d-%m-%y-%T').csv
csv_path=/home/name/project
filename_no_path=/home/name/project


sed --version : sed (GNU sed) 4.4
```

Comment: Seems to be Ok! Can you share the contents of `test.sh` containing `path` string that you are trying to replace here?

Comment: @Inian is there a way to attach it? The script is kinda big...

Comment: You can add only the relevant parts, lines containing `path` string and also output of `sed --version`

Comment: @Inian done. I have added everything you requested :) Thanks!

Comment: FYI, if you do not need to do it all the time, this can be done with most editors (search and replace on all opened files).

Comment: @Nic3500 i need to automate an installation of some stuff + running the tests. Basically, one who uses my scripts, should run 2 scripts maximum, and then everything should be ready (no modifications/replaces/other stuff). One who uses my scripts, might not have extensive knowledge :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just add a `^` before the search expression to limit the substitutions to the pattern beginning the line.

```
sed -i -e "s|^path=.*|path=${path}|g" "${path}/scripts/test.sh"
```

The result should match what you're expecting:

```
path=/tmp
pic_path=${path}/test_plan/tests/*
log_name=results_$(date +'%d-%m-%y-%T').log
log_path=${path}/test_plan/logs/${log_name}
csv_name=results_$(date +'%d-%m-%y-%T').csv
csv_path=${path}/test_plan/test_results/${csv_name}
filename_no_path="${f##*/}"
```

Comment: This works, but i cannot understand why... Can you please edit the answer, and explain what does that ^ (thing) means?? (shall be easier visible to others). Thank you very much! @hi olaf

Comment: `^` at the start of a regular expression insures that only lines starting with the regular expression are matched. It works the same way as the `$` for the end of a regular expression. As to why the ${path} were originally substituted that was also baffling :-)